# Pure C OpenCL vs Python OpenCL performance

Tags: c, performance, opencl, performance-testing, pyopencl

I am looking for performance measurement between Python wrapper to OpenCL and Pure C OpenCL. Performance measurements can varies with time, memory, etc.. 
- Are there any benchmarks available?
- What should be the expectation about the time performance differences?
- What kind of tasks (parallel of course...) should make a difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is likely that PyOpenCL is your best choice.  I would choose to use C only in very specific situations (a super-critical need for speed/low-latency on the **host**).  For most casual parallel programs, it is fine for the **host** side to have plenty of slack, because all the real work gets done on the **device**.

You can consider PyOpenCL and OpenCL to have identical performance on the **device**.

Maybe use C if you are, like... designing a self-driving car, and every millisecond/amp matters.  But even in that situation, it is likely that Python could be used effectively.

The best way to figure out if your specific program is slowed down is to time your code.  For PyOpenCL that means:

```
import time
```

and

```
cl.command_queue_properties.PROFILING_ENABLE
```

Many smart companies and individuals choose to code first in Python, because they can build a flexible, working prototype quickly.  If they end up needing more **host** performance later, it is relatively easy to port Python to C.

Hope that helps!

Comment: indeed helps, and reasonable. However, real measurements are a must to support this assumption. If so, the conclusion is that in manner of cost of value python is THE platform for GPGPU programming

Answer (score 3):

OpenCL uses precompiled programs, that later sent to device for execution. They are so-called "kernels". These kernels are deployed to be executed on end-device. This means main cost that must be measured is OpenCL implementation API I/O. Therefore, you can't rely on memory/CPU measurements, as real OpenCL part will use same of them.

AFAIK, no benchmarks available, but it is not hard to do one, if you will need it (matrix multiplication is hello world example, overall).

OpenCL is not that kind, that uses I/O on every CPU cycle. Field of use - really big data processing, that uses one big input, a lot of processing operations, and one output (no matter small or big). No one says that OpenCL can't be used with many I/O and minimal calculation variations, but implementation API overhead not worth it.

Expectations must be that I/O is pretty same fast in approximation to overall application performance.

Comment: What is the case when I have multiple outputs and heavy calculations, and also another case when the processing is lightweight, for example median filter?

Comment: @hellfire769 PyOpenCL implementation does not lack performance that much, AFAIK, as it simple wrapper over OpenCL API. And very good one. For your cases it will do job right. It just must.

Answer (score 3):

There is a benchmark here: https://github.com/bennylp/saxpy-benchmark, comparing PyOpenCL against OpenCL as well as other frameworks/methods such as CUDA, plain C++, Numpy, R, Octave, and even TensorFlow (disclaimer: I'm the author)

According to the benchmark results, the performance difference between OpenCL and PyOpenCL varies too wildly. The PyOpenCL GPU target is almost 7x slower than OpenCL, but for the CPU target PyOpenCL is actually more than 2x faster than OpenCL!

Comment: Excellent benchmarks! Very informative between the languages and OS. Thanks for your hard work.